# Bad space when using footnote with csquotes

Tags: spacing, csquotes

I use `csquotes` for quotation and I want to use `\hyphenblockquote` with a footnote at the end of the quotation. Currently I observe a very weird withespace after the quotation. Do you any idea to how I can remove it?

**MNWE:**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\usepackage[autostyle=true,debug=true,autopunct=true,csdisplay = true]{csquotes}
\makeatletter \XeTeXinterchartoks 4095 \french@punctguillend = {\xpg@unskip\nobreakspace}

\usepackage[
  style=authortitle,
]{biblatex}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{article,
  author = {Nachname, Vorname},
  title = {Titel des Zeitschriftenartikels},
  journal = {Zeitschrift},
  year = {2006},
  volume = {6},
  pages = {19--75}
}
@ARTICLE{articleb,
  author = {Nom, Prenom},
  title = {Translated text},
  journal = {hein},
  year = {2010},
  volume = {8},
  pages = {40--110}
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\SetCiteCommand{\footcite}

\begin{document}
%%not working
\hyphenblockquote{french}{Etre exclu d'une communauté sans faire partie d'une autre, me trouver dès ma petite enfance par-delà les paroisses, catalogué par aucune car individu isolé et seul: voilà ce qui détermina mon attitude et mon destin pour l'ensemble de ma vie. Fut-ce pour moi une chance ou une malchance, c'est ce qui doit apparaître au cours de ce récit de vie. Si j'ai aujourd'hui l'impression que ce fut finalement une chance, je n'en ai pas moins payé le prix fort toute ma vie. \footnote{\footcite[\hyphenquote{german}{Daß ich aus einer Gemeinschaft ausgeschlossen war, ohne zu einer andern zu gehören, daß ich also schon in meiner frühesten Kindheit jenseits der Gemeinden stand, von keiner abgestempelt, als isoliertes, einsames Individuum – das bestimmte meine Haltung und mein Schicksal für das ganze Leben. Ob das für mich ein Glück oder ein Unglück geworden ist, soll im Ablauf dieser Lebensgeschichte offenbar werden. Wenn es, wie mir heute scheint, letztlich ein Glück war, so wurde es ein langes Leben hindurch mit dem schwersten Leid bezahlt}, p. ][]{article}\footcite{articleb}}}

\hyphenblockquote{french}{Etre exclu d'une communauté sans faire partie d'une autre, me trouver dès ma petite enfance par-delà les paroisses, catalogué par aucune car individu isolé et seul: voilà ce qui détermina mon attitude et mon destin pour l'ensemble de ma vie. Fut-ce pour moi une chance ou une malchance, c'est ce qui doit apparaître au cours de ce récit de vie. Si j'ai aujourd'hui l'impression que ce fut finalement une chance, je n'en ai pas moins payé le prix fort toute ma vie. \footnote{\hyphenquote{german}{Daß ich aus einer Gemeinschaft ausgeschlossen war, ohne zu einer andern zu gehören, daß ich also schon in meiner frühesten Kindheit jenseits der Gemeinden stand, von keiner abgestempelt, als isoliertes, einsames Individuum – das bestimmte meine Haltung und mein Schicksal für das ganze Leben. Ob das für mich ein Glück oder ein Unglück geworden ist, soll im Ablauf dieser Lebensgeschichte offenbar werden. Wenn es, wie mir heute scheint, letztlich ein Glück war, so wurde es ein langes Leben hindurch mit dem schwersten Leid bezahlt}\footcite[, p. ][]{article}\footcite{articleb}}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand the question right: Do you mean the white space right before the footnote marks in the text (not the footer)? Then you should remove the space before `\footnote{}`. Also, you shouldn't use `\footcite` inside a footnote! As you already are in a footnote, `\cite` is enough -- and you won't get a warning that you have nested notes.

Comment: @Andreas I don't see the space before `\footnote`.... Thank you. It is my mistake!! I know about warning but the result. I will correct it. Using `\footcite` inside a `\footnote` does not give the same result as `\cite` . In fact  `\footcite` inside a `\footnote` leads to obtain the same result as `\footnote{\parencite{..}}`.